# Passing Vector from one class to another for manipulation

Tags: c++, vector, parameter-passing

I want to get the vector

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > Ticket;
```

from one class (User) to another (Game) in order to manipulate the contents there.

Specifically I need it in a function (compareNumbers).

Currently in main.cpp I have this code:

```
#include "User.h"
#include "Game.h"

int k = game.compareNumbers(user.<int>Ticket);
```

*(unnecessary includes and other code left out for simplicity)*

In User.h is the declaration for for the vector (public) and in User.cpp the Vector is populated.

I suspect it is more complicated due it being a vector containing vectors but I'm not sure.

In Game.cpp I have

```
int Game::compareNumbers(std::vector< std::vector<int> > Ticket)
// Some code
```

The error that I am presented with is 'expected a member name' on the first < in main.
However I suspect that there are more errors than that.

Also I think maybe I should be passing by reference, but I'm not sure. and I'm not sure how to do that, and possibly const aswell, in compareNumbers, I am not modifying the vector, purely comparing its contents with the contents of another vector, again, not sure?

Comment: Just pass in user.Ticket. Also use a const reference, instead of passing in a vector. Only use non-const if you need to modify the contents of the vector which doesn't seem to be the case. Edit: Just saw @Dietmar Kuhl's answer. Basically that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `user` has a member `Ticket`, you can pass this object to your `Game::compareNumbers()` function just using

```
int = game.compareNumbers(user.Ticket);
```

As things are declared, this will copy the `std::vector<std::vector<int> >`, however, which is probably not quite what you want. If you really just want to look at the numbers (the name of the function indicates you kind of do), you'd pass the object using a `const&`:

```
int Game::compareNumbers(std::vector<std::vector<int> > const& Ticker) {
    // ...
}
```

If `compareNumbers()` actually needs to modify its argument, you'd omit the `const` but keep the reference: without the reference a copy is passed on and modified which wouldn't affect the original `user.Ticket` object.